# How can I simplify similar method calls between a group of static objects?

Tags: c#, static

I have a handful of static "shape" classes that I am using in my program, and since each of the static classes needs to perform the same kind of operations, I'm wondering if there's a way to genericize the method call. **If the classes weren't static, I'd simply use an interface.**

Here's the gist of my situation:

```
public static Triangle
{

  public int getNumVerts()
  {
    return 3;
  }

  public bool isColliding()
  {
    return Triangle Collision Code Here
  }

}

public static Square
{

  public int getNumVerts()
  {
    return 4;
  }

  public bool isColliding()
  {
    return Square Collision Code Here
  }

}
```

What I'd prefer to do is simply call `Shape.getNumVerts()`, instead of my current switch statement:

```
switch (ShapeType)
{
  case ShapeType.Triangle:
      Triangle.GetNumVerts();
  case ShapeType.Square:
      Square.GetNumVerts();
}
```

I could simply use polymorphism if I used singletons instead of static classes, but singletons are to be avoided, and I'd need to pass a ton of references around so that I could do processing, as needed, on the individual shapes.

Is there a way to group these static classes, or is the switch statement as good as it's going to get?

Comment: Why are singletons to be avoided? You have a scenario where sinlgetons would solve your problems, why not use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you need separate `Triangle` and `Square` classes. You could eliminate them and have only `Shape` class with methods accepting `ShapeType` argument. But it also comes with`switch` actually.

```
public static class Shape
{
    public static int GetNumVerts(ShapeType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ShapeType.Triangle:return 3;
            case ShapeType.Square:return 4;
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

As for `switch`, I guess it's quite common and normal to use it this way.

Yet you may have separate `Triangle` and `Square` classes, and have your switch within `Shape.GetNumVerts` method. It will let you call `Shape.GetNumVerts(ShapeType.Triangle);`, i.e. `switch` is encapsulated within `Shape` class  and used only once there.

```
public static class Shape
{
    public static int GetNumVerts(ShapeType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ShapeType.Triangle:return Triangle.GetNumVerts();
            case ShapeType.Square:return Square.GetNumVerts();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```